How does parallel transport works on the lower triangular matrix with positive diagonal element?
Suppose $LT^{+}(n)$ is the lower triangular matrix with positive diagonal element. The $LT^{+}(n)$ can be seen as a lie group structure. For all $\Gamma,\Gamma' \in LT^{+}(n)$, $\xi \in T_{\Gamma}LT^{+}(n)\simeq LT(n)$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$, the basic operations are given by:
(Exponential map) $\text{Exp}_{\Gamma}(t\xi) = \Gamma \exp(t \Gamma^{-1} \xi)$,
(Logarithm map) $\text{Log}_{\Gamma}(\Gamma') = \Gamma \log(\Gamma^{-1} \Gamma')$,
(Geodesic) $\gamma_{\Gamma \to \Gamma'}(t) = \text{Exp}_{\Gamma}(t \Gamma^{-1} \text{Log}_{\Gamma}(\Gamma')) = \Gamma (\Gamma^{-1} \Gamma')^t$.
This approach relies on the canonical Cartan-Schouten connection to define the group exponential and the notion of group means, as opposed to the Levi-Civita connection. However, the concept of parallel transport on $LT^{+}(n)$ remains unclear. How does parallel transport work on $LT^{+}(n)$?
Reference
[1] Thanwerdas, Yann and Pennec, Xavier, "Theoretically and computationally convenient geometries on full-rank correlation matrices," SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications, 2022.
